# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. EF Code-first asp.net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I've seen this question asked many times before, but they were always targetting the older means of adding connection strings through the App.config files.

I am using an asp.net Core 3.1 Web application which uses the appsettings.json to create a connection string. Which is as follows:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=WS-NAME;Database=BookListRazor;User ID=sa;Password=****;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  },
```

I have tried using this SSMS login, but I also tried creating a new one that wasn't sa. Both these users have dbcreator, public & sysadmin server roles enabled.

When I try create the database manually using SSMS, it works perfectly fine. Whereas when I use the same login details as part of my connection string, I am returned with the error

```
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

I have tried many different ways that're suggested as solutions for this but none seemed to work.  I'd appreciate any suggestions you guys may have.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a WebForm app type in Asp.NET Core 3.1 ?

Comment: @Kaj I meant web aplpication.

Comment: So your login credentials works in SSMS but not with Asp.net app? Have you tried to run VS as Administrator ?

Comment: @Kaj Yes that is correct, I am currently running both SSMS and VS as Administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `User ID=sa;Password=****;Trusted_Connection=True` is wrong.  You set Trusted_Connection to False when passing a User ID and Password.  Otherwise the Windows identity of the client program is used to connect to the SQL Server

From Docs:

> If User ID and Password are specified and Integrated Security is set
>   to true, the **User ID and Password will be ignored** and Integrated
>   Security will be used.

[SqlConnection.ConnectionString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: You are an absolute hero! I can not believe I missed that. Thank you very much David! you've literally saved me from such a stressful day :) It's working perfectly fine now!